# MobileMe iDisk Folders 

Tags: mobileme, icloud

What are the following (default) iDisk folders used for:

- Backup
- Groups
- Library
- Sites
- Software
- Web

If you delete them and wait a few minutes they will re-appear, but I do not know what they are used for. There is a document in them explaining their use, but it is still not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Backup** is used by the MobileMe Backup application. I don't recommend using it.
- **Groups** is for a now defunct Groups feature that they used to have.
- **Library** is used for MobileMe's syncing feature - primarily for Preferences and Bookmarks.
- **Sites** is used for webpages or anything you want shared at `http://homepage.mac.com/username/`. Note: PHP files, CGI files, etc. don't work. It only works with static content.
- **Software** contains free software provided by Apple to MobileMe customers (eg. the Backup application) - this doesn't affect your disk usage.
- **Web** is a folder used by iWeb - otherwise it's nearly identical to the Sites folder but is available at `http://web.me.com/username`

Comment: Ah, so they are mostly useless for a lot of people. Wish they could be permanently removed :(

Comment: Why do you want to remove them ? They don't take any space (if empty).